# convert myNSArray to xml format in ipad app?

Tags: xml, ipad, nsarray

I am developing a SOAP based application. soap request is a list of questions and i need to answer each questions and send the response in xml format. i have collected all those answers in NSArray. now i need to convert this array to xml format.

the header fields for each question is

```
 {productid,questionid,valueid,answerText}
```

and my answer array is

```
 {3,2,2,black color}
```

I need to generate these answer arrays in the xml format

something like

```
 <productid>3</productid> <questionid>2</questionid> <valueid>2</valueid> <answerText>black color</answerText>
```

I may have multiple questions to answer. Finally I need to send all these answers in the xml format

Comment: see, my app is a quiz based app and i need to select the answers from list of items for each questions (probably radio buttons) . at the end of all these i need to send this answers in a xml format as response. the response should contain the fields "which question was answered, answer number, value, and text",

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSArray *array in allQuestions) {
    [res appendString:@"<question>\n"];
    [res appendFormat:@"<productid>%@</productid>\n", [array objectAtIndex:0]];
    [res appendFormat:@"<questionid>%@</questionid>\n", [array objectAtIndex:1]];
    [res appendFormat:@"<valueid>%@</valueid>\n", [array objectAtIndex:2]];
    [res appendFormat:@"<answerText>%@</answerText>\n", [array objectAtIndex:3]];
    [res appendFormat:@"</question>\n"];
}
```

assuming allQuestions is the array containing all the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\myNSXML.xml", null);
string[] Headers = { "productid", "questionid", "valueid", "answerText" };
string[] Answers = { "3", "2", "2", "black color" };
textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
textWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
for (int i = 0; i < Headers.Length; i++)
{
  textWriter.WriteStartElement(Headers[i]);
  textWriter.WriteString(Answers[i]);
  textWriter.WriteEndElement();
}
textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
textWriter.Close();
```

Find following XML file named "myNSXML.xml" in C drive

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Root>
<productid>3</productid> 
<questionid>2</questionid> 
<valueid>2</valueid> 
<answerText>black color</answerText> 
</Root>
```

I hope this will help you...